# Python: generating list outputs as a table

Tags: python-2.7

I have the data in two lists.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
```

So I use a nested for loop:

```
for a in list1:
    for b in list2:
        distance = a - b
        print distance
```

This returns:

```
-5
-6
-7
..
..
..
-4
-5
```

I would like to have the output as tabular format:

```
 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9
 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8
 ...
 ...
 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for a in list1:
    for b in list2:
        distance = a - b
        print distance,
    print
```

The output I get:

```
-5 -6 -7 -8 -9
-4 -5 -6 -7 -8
-3 -4 -5 -6 -7
-2 -3 -4 -5 -6
-1 -2 -3 -4 -5
```

Comment: Can we put this in a csv, while keeping the tabular format?

Comment: Well, if it's just numbers then it's enough to print a comma between adjacent numbers. If you have to put strings (thus they can contain commas) you should look the `csv` module up.